# android java what is a long[ ][ ]?

Tags: android, statistics, apache-commons, chi-squared, apache-commons-math

I need to do the chiSquaredTest. I'm using the Apache Commons Math library but not sure what is a `long[][]` what the difference to a `long[]` ?  Here is the method description :

```
  public double chiSquareTest(long[][] counts)
                 throws NullArgumentException,
                        DimensionMismatchException,
                        NotPositiveException,
                        MaxCountExceededException
```

Returns the observed significance level, or p-value, associated with a chi-square test of independence based on the input counts array, viewed as a two-way table.

The rows of the 2-way table are count[ 0 ], ... , count[count.length - 1]

> Preconditions:

- List item All counts must be ≥ 0.
- The count array must be rectangular (i.e. all count[ i ] subarrays must have the same length).
- The 2-way table represented by counts must have at least 2 columns and at least 2 rows.
- If any of the preconditions are not met, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

> Parameters:

- counts - array representation of 2-way table

> Returns:

- p-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long[]` - it is one dimensional array.

```
long[] array = new long[4];

/* result of that array
{0, 0, 0, 0}
*/
```

`long[][]` - it is array of arrays / two dimensional array.

```
long[][] array2 = new long[4][];
array2[0] = new long[1];
array2[1] = new long[2];
array2[2] = new long[4];
array2[3] = new long[3];

/* result of that array
{
    {0},
    {0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0},
}
*/
```

or it can be like that:

```
long[][] array = new long[4][4];

/* result of that array
{
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
}
*/
```

For more examples go to [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: Hello! ok i got it.
so if i want to add a value to thw first row would be

Comment: Hello! ok i got it.
so if i want to add a values to the first row would be 

array2[0][0] = (long) 3.2;   ---first,first 
array2[1][0] = 8;                ---first,second

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the ChiSquareTest class in Apache Commons Math provides two different measures:

1. Goodness of fit test: use `chiSquareTest(double[] expected, double[] observed)` - tests if your observed data comes from a claimed distribution.
2. Test of independence: use `chiSquareTest(double[][] counts)` - tests if two different variables are associated with each other.

These two tests are slightly different and the results will be different.

Edit: as the question is actually related to the chidst function of Excel and how to calculate the same result in Java, the solution with Apache Commons Math3 would be as follows:

```
ChiSquaredDistribution dist = new ChiSquaredDistribution(df);
double chidst = 1 - dist.cumulativeProbability(chi);
```

Comment: Yeah! i need the Test of independence usually i do it in excel and whit chidst function i need two values chidst(chi,df), still can't figurate out how to do it in java using there libraries and the two dimensional array do you have an idea?

Comment: The chidst function in excel computes the right-tailed probability of the ChiSquare distribution. With commons-math you can get the same like this: ChiSquaredDistribution dist = new ChiSquaredDistribution(df);
double chidst = 1 - dist.cumulativeProbability(chi);

Comment: I suggest that you update your question to reflect what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! yes i got confuse. I found this post [Why does tail probability in apache math drop to zero after 1E-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773499/why-does-tail-probability-in-apache-math-drop-to-zero-after-1e-16)
is actually better to use regularizedGammaQ();
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html

Comment: Well that is only relevant for corner-cases that you will probably not encounter anyways.